# I found a white space at the bottom while making the website mobile responsive on some of the phones and tablets

Tags: css, iphone, vue.js, media-queries, quasar-framework

[This is the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ISbx.png) 
I found a white space at the bottom while making the website mobile responsive on some of the phones and tablets as you guys can see in the image. Please post your solutions. I am using Quasar with Vue. Also, I found it a little bit on the Macbook as well.

Thank you

I tried some of the solutions.

Comment: it is very difficult to help you with just an image. No one will be able to help you with this. So please put up the code of your component so people can look at and suggest solutions. Ideally use source like stackblitz to setup a minimum working example which people can see and help you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please read the [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I found the solution by myself, the answer is that I always set the first q-layout height equal to the window height so these bugs can be fixed. In my case I just simply

```
<q-layout style="height: 800px">
to
<q-layout style="height: 1000px">
```